# Is it possible to use C++ in SDL for Android?

Tags: c++, android, sdl, c, porting

I have successfully compiled SDL for Android using the example, which uses C. Is it possible to use C++ too?

I am trying to port a C++ game which uses SDL 2 to Android.

If it is possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principles are exactly the same:

1. you write your game in c++
2. create the cmake files to compile your project
3. hit ndk_build

In general ndk_build can compile both c and c++, so it doesn't really matter which one you choose. I've actually only used SDL2 bundled with c++ code and it compiles perfectly.

Comment: Did you compile SDL itself in C and added C++ code? Or did you compile both in C++?

Comment: SDL2 comes with a cmakefile. I just added that library in my own cmake using "`$(call import-module, SDL)`"

Comment: by the way there is no indicator in cmake file to tell whether the project is written in c or c++, except file extensions. you can take a look at [my complete cmake file](http://pastebin.com/N6XpyhZL) if it helps.